# What is the difference between old groups and new groups in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, android

Can anybody tell me what the **difference is between a new group** (one you now create) **and old groups** (one you created a couple of months ago) **on Facebook**?

I notice that, in the Facebook for Android application, the new style groups are visible, but the old ones aren't.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [excellent article here](http://www.allfacebook.com/new-facebook-groups-2010-10) that explains the new features of Groups in Facebook.

The main purpose was to integrate Facebook groups as main component of Facebook. To quote the article:

> The primary idea behind Facebook
>   groups is that it’s a form of ongoing
>   collaboration product. If you want to
>   have a simple way to communicate with
>   your family members, you can use the
>   groups product. Ultimately there are
>   countless purposes for creating
>   groups.

Comment: Thanks for the link . Interesting article . I'm still not sure whether I would like to change my existing groups to new groups, or not. One advantage is there for sure: the Android Facebook application will list new groups, but not old ones. But that's an advantage for me directly ... not necessarily one for my group members.